# Calibri font changed in Excel after Windows 10 AU

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, fonts

After installing 1607 AU in Windows 10 today, fonts in Excel (2013) look changed. It is using the default Calibri font and text looks the same, but numbers are somewhat wider or larger and they look like they are from a completely different font. Any idea what could be causing this or how to fix it?

[image]

Looking at the `Windows.old` folder, the Calibri font files did in fact change.

Here are the files from `Windows.old\Windows\Fonts`:

```
30.10.2015  09:17           942 348 calibri.ttf
30.10.2015  09:17           904 432 calibrib.ttf
30.10.2015  09:17           999 152 calibrii.ttf
30.10.2015  09:17           808 596 calibril.ttf
30.10.2015  09:17           923 408 calibrili.ttf
30.10.2015  09:18           959 652 calibriz.ttf
```

And here from the current `Windows\Fonts`:

```
16.07.2016  13:42         1 329 860 calibri.ttf
16.07.2016  13:42         1 295 340 calibrib.ttf
16.07.2016  13:42         1 095 696 calibrii.ttf
16.07.2016  13:42         1 131 948 calibril.ttf
16.07.2016  13:42           962 964 calibrili.ttf
16.07.2016  13:42         1 074 860 calibriz.ttf
```

From this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4wvsmn/did_the_anniversary_update_remove_certain_fonts/d6bji1e) thread it seems I'm not the only one having this issue.

Comment: There are some solutions in the reddit thread you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that the digits look exactly the same when browsing the font through Control Panel\Fonts (or through Explorer, which redirects there), the digits have definately changed in 1607. **Please note, that you will always see the installed version when browsing the font contents, regardless of which font file you open.** What I find funny is, that the dates of the new font files are 16.07.2016. After making a second check (which you can make yourself with Properties | Details on the font files) I noticed that in fact the font version changed from 6.12 to 6.14. So, I hope this answers your first question "what could be causing this?".

For me, personally, this problem is maybe more a discomfort than a real problem, but it meant I couldn't use Calibri for my spreadsheets anymore and had to revert back to Verdana, which I stiil use for some of them, but Calibri is more suitable for easy-to-read data.

The solution was to use the old fonts from the Windows.old folder instead of the new ones. The hurdle here is that you have to delete the installed fonts first and then install the old ones again. For this, you have to delete the font entries from the registry in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts

(please make sure to export the whole key before you delete the font names, so you have a backup). After that you need to give yourself permissions to the font folder in C:\Windows\WinSxS named

> amd64_microsoft-windows-font-truetype-calibri_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_181a98c8067730e2

by first setting the owner to Administrators and then change and apply Full Permissions to the folder and propagate them to the files inside. After that you can move the font files to a backup folder with the 1607 6.14 fonts and copy inside this folder the old fonts from 1511. When this is done, you can go and delete the files from the C:\Windows\Fonts folder using Command Prompt (Admin) - right click on the Windows/Start icon/button - go to the C:\Windows\Fonts folder

> cd C:\Windows\Fonts

and use the command

> del calibri*

You may double check in the Registry Editor to see if the font names are still missing in the list.

After you have done all this, you can copy the old files in the Control Panel\Fonts folder or in Explorer in C:\Windows\Fonts, which is the same.
Then restart your Windows (your PC) and Windows should regenerate the registry entries with the same file names (if you do not delete the installed font files first from the folder and just delete them from the registry, after you "install" the fonts, they will be installed with an appendix like '_0' in the font file name, which will be seen in the registry).

My check in Excel shows that after this procedure (if I have not missed something by mistake in the description here), the Calibri font is back to "normal" i.e. version 6.12 and looks nice again.

I hope that I have been helpful and that all those explanations will help someone with less experience in digging in Windows. You may use the following for reference, but keep in mind that we change the font, so there are differences.

http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Protected-System-Fonts-in-Windows-7

Comment: I used similar approach to replace the font, but for me it still shows the new digits, even if I have v6.12 in properties/details.

Comment: At this point I would only suggest that you do it again from scratch. It may show the 6.12 but use the new font, so it is best to do all steps, especially the deleting and replacing the WinSxS files, otherwise Windows may "recover" the font files from there. Have you tried with a new workbook and setting different fonts and set again Calibri? If it is not the font, it may be something with the display settings for the font size or something with the theme.

Comment: I have checked today and the numbers are displayed correctly. So it seems few more reboots convinced Windows to really use the old font files.

Answer (score 1):

[Fixes or workarounds for recent issues in Excel for Windows @ support.office.com (Applies To: Excel 2016, Excel 2013)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-Excel-for-Windows-49d932ce-0240-49cf-94df-1587d9d97093)

> When using ClearType with the Windows Anniversary update, Excel column widths can be larger than in earlier versions of Windows. This happens in only some fonts, such as Calibri. It can affect all versions of Office 2016. We are working on releasing a fix. 
>   The workaround is to turn off ClearType, or switch to a font that gives your reports the appearance you want.